# Find string inside of the text file. Then getting the following line and need to Split by Index of and substring

Tags: java, string, substring, java.util.scanner, indexof

Find string inside of a text file. Then get the following line and split by `indexOf()` and `substring()`.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

public class FileReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("a.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(f);
        String airportcode = "HOI";

        while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fin.nextLine();
            int firstindex = line.indexOf(airportcode);

            if (firstindex > 0) {
                int Code = line.indexOf("|");
                int Country = line.lastIndexOf("|",Code);
                int State = line.indexOf("|", Country);
                int City = line.indexOf("|", State);
                int Airport = line.indexOf("|", City);
                System.out.println(Code);
                System.out.println(Country);
                System.out.println(State);
                System.out.println(City);
                System.out.println(Airport);
                System.out.println(line.substring(0, Code));
                break;
            }
        }

        fin.close();
    }
}
```

The 1 sout looks like this:
`French Polynesia|HOI|Hao|Tuamotos|Hao Airport`
I need using only `indexOf()` and `substring()`,
but I need it like this:

```
French Polynesia
HOI
Hao
Tuamotos
Hao Airport
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you always the same number of fields for every line of the file and always separated by `|` ?

Comment: French Polynesia|HOI|Hao|Tuamotos|Hao Airport    

 I need to separate  "|" @dariosicily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the assumption you always the same number of fields, in your case 5 separated by the character `|` you can solve the problem without using `String split` method but just `indexOf` and `substring` like below:

```
String s = "French Polynesia|HOI|Hao|Tuamotos|Hao Airport";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    int endIndex = s.indexOf("|");
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, endIndex));
    s = s.substring(endIndex + 1);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

The code will print all the fields that can be assigned to your distinct variables.

Comment: This is Working but Last data not commeing Out

Comment: @sandunwijerathneJerry  Forgotten one line, string s contains the last data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- file content has lines with the following structure: `French Polynesia|HOI|Hao|Tuamotos|Hao Airport`
- you need to print only those lines that contain `"HOI"` string
- you have to use `indexOf` and `substring` only.

Here is code snippet that should work for you (file `a.dat` is located in `resources` folder):

```java
package example;

import java.util.*; // for Scanner
import java.io.*; // for File and IOException

public class FileReadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(
            Objects.requireNonNull(FileReadTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("a.dat")).getFile()
        );
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(f);
        String airportcode = "HOI";
        while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fin.nextLine();
            if (line.indexOf(airportcode) != -1) {
                int firstindex;
                while ((firstindex = line.indexOf("|")) != -1) {
                    System.out.println(line.substring(0, firstindex));
                    line = line.substring(firstindex + 1);
                }
                System.out.println(line); // last data 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, @fabasoad your answer also working properly